# Why can't I access FileName of uploaded file in ASP.NET MVC when uploaded using Microsoft Edge?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, microsoft-edge

I have a simple file upload page and an ASP.NET MVC Controller to process the uploaded file. In Chrome and Firefox, everything works as expected. But it seems that Edge uploads the file differently, such that the Controller sees that a file has been uploaded, but shows FileName as "" and ContentLength as 0.

Here is the cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <h3>Upload File</h3>
    File:
    <input type="file" name="UploadedFile" />
    <input type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

And in the controller I have:

```
HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["UploadedFile"];
```

Afterward the `file` object is not null, but its `ContentLength` is 0 and `FileName` is an empty string. With Chrome and Firefox, these values contain the correct data.

What is different about how Edge handles file uploads?

Comment: Just tried this code and it worked for me in EDGE. Are you sure you are uploading a valid file ?

Comment: If `ContentLength == 0` then no file was uploaded.

Comment: I used the same page and uploaded the same file with all three browsers - only got `ContentLength == 0` with Edge.

Comment: Oh it seems that [this was the problem](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8648097/). The file I was trying to upload was an Excel file, and it was still open in Excel. So you were right @Shyju the file was the issue. It also seems that Edge handles the open Excel file differently than the other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with my code. I was uploading an Excel spreadsheet that was also open in Excel at the same time, and [Edge uploads Word and Excel files as 0 bytes when the file is open](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8648097/).